# Is it possible to have an Oracle Database "alias login" for another login with its own credentials?

Tags: oracle, credentials

Our group has the following situation:

We have a large number of applications that access a central database.  All of these applications use the same "application" database credential with a password that is not particularly secure, and therefore we fall afoul of our corporation's completely legitimate security guidelines.  Some of these applications run on WebLogic, others are standalone java apps, others are simply shell scripts, but all use the same username:password credentials, which are encoded in one of a variety of ways that are less than optimally secure:  hardcoded, written in various configuration files of differing levels of security, etc.

This setup, which is rather old, is a nightmare to change.  If we change the password on the database, a plethora of configuration files in different locations also need to change, which requires starting and stopping various servers, config changes etc.  There would inevitably be outages of intolerable length.

If it were possible to create a second database user, as an "alias" to the first, with identical rights and privileges to the first user on the first user's associated schema, but with a different password, this configuration nightmare would be eased. The user could be created on the database, and then, more or less at leisure, each application could be reconfigured to use the "alias", without more than very brief outages for each application.  Then, when security rules dictating that it's time to change the passwords again, the same process could be done in reverse.

**UPDATE - the requirement in the following paragraph was not in the original question.**

The reason that I am specifying "alias" is that the second login should work EXACTLY like the first one, that is, no SQL should need to change:  i.e. `SELECT * from some_table` should continue to work without requiring a change to `SELECT * from first_user.some_table`.

It's quite possible that such a system already exists, under a name that I'm not expecting, but so far my searches haven't shown me what I'm looking for.

Has anyone ever had to deal with this situation and how was it handled?  Perhaps there is a solution to it that is different from my "alias" idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you are describing is [proxy authentication](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/proxy-users-and-connect-through.php#proxy-user-and-connect-through).  You can create a user `A` with its own password but with the ability to connect to the database as a different user `B`.  The only downside is that it can be a bit of a pain to figure out how each framework that an application might use does proxy authentication.  And taking full advantage of proxy authentication may require making code changes to some of your applications.

Taking a step back, it's not clear to me that you really need to get that sophisticated.  Unless all your applications need to be creating and dropping objects in the target schema (which would be exceptionally unusual), it sounds like you just want to

- Create a role that has all the privileges you want the account to have.
- Create a new user
- Grant that newly created role to the newly created user
- Switch an application to use the newly created user

If what you really want, for example, is to allow the new user to do DML on every table in the schema

```
-- Create the role that will have privileges to do DML on every table in
-- the FOO schema
CREATE ROLE foo_all_dml;

-- Grant privileges to the role
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT *
              FROM dba_tables
             WHERE owner = 'FOO')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
      'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON foo.' || 
        t.table_name || 
       ' TO foo_all_dml';
  END LOOP;
END;
/

-- Create the new user
CREATE USER bar 
  IDENTIFIED BY <<new password>>;

-- Grant the role to the user
GRANT foo_all_dml
   TO bar;
```

As new objects get added, you'd grant appropriate privileges to the role and all the users you've created with that role would be get it.

If you want to avoid qualifying object names, you could create synonyms (public or private) that refer to the objects in the original schema.  If you want to create a private synonym in the `BAR` schema for every table in the `FOO` schema

```
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT *
              FROM dba_tables
             WHERE owner = 'FOO')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
      'CREATE SYNONYM bar.' || t.table_name ||
        ' FOR foo.' || t.table_name;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You could also create a login trigger that did an

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = foo
```

when you log in to `bar`.

Comment: @Justin_Cave Thanks.  Is there a TO clause missing from your GRANT statement?

Comment: @SteveCohen - Why yes, yes I was.  Should be corrected.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @Justin_Cave Thanks again.  Please see Dmitry's post below which offers essentially the same solution as yours, but falls short because I edited the original question to add the requirement that all SQL code should work as before without needing to specify the schema owner for database objects.  Does your solution fall short similarly?

Comment: @SteveCohen - Updated to include the creation of synonyms (or setting the `current_schema`) to avoid qualifying object names.

Comment: @Justin_Cave Thanks, I've upvoted your solution and will further mark it as "the" solution if no one comes up with anything else after a few more hours.

Answer (score 2):

You can use roles. Create role:

```
create role universal_app_role identified by 123;
```

Then you need to find all desired priviledes and grant them to this role, for example:

```
grant create table to universal_app_role;
```

After that you can grant this role to any user:

```
grant universal_app_role to john_smith;
```

After that you can also add any new privileges to this role (`universal_app_role`), and all users with this role will get it.

**EDIT**
You have updated your question and my answer became less appropriate now. If you want to access database objects without writing a schema name, you can create public synonyms for that objects:

```
create public synonym some_table for first_user.some_table;
```

Comment: Sorry about the update.  That would require a lot of synonym creation.  Very annoying.  I've never liked the way oracle treats schema and user as a strict one-to-one match.